# Value is being displayed 2 times and .map function not working - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, array.prototype.map

1. why my todo data is not showing values at first time but showing at 2nd time and why is being displayed 2 times
   [image: Console Image]

```
   const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        todolist()
        
    },[])

    const todolist = () => {
        if (typeof window !== undefined) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("jwt")) {
                let temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jwt"));
                
                getToDo(temp.user._id, temp.token).then(response => {
                   
                    setTodos(response)
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
        }
    }

    const getToData = () => {
       
        console.log('todo', todos.todos)
      
    }
```

2.When i apply .map function i get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

```
const getToData = () => {
       
        console.log('todo', todos.todos)

        let userTodos = todos.todos
        //here is where i get error
        return userTodos.map((current, index) => {
            return <Todo todo={current} key={index} />
        })
    }
```

Could you please help me in fixing these 2 issues

Answer (score 2):

**todos** is an object, not an array. Thus you need to initialize it as the following:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState({})
```

And calling endpoint is asynchronous, therefore you are gaining the empty values while the endpoint call is progressing. So, you need to set up a fallback to **todos.todos** in order to avoid having `undefined` value as the following:

```
const userTodos = todos.todos || []
```

This should get rid of your problems. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

**useEffect** hook is called after your component is rendered. So when your component rendered first time it will show empty records and then useEffect called and you are setting the **setState** and it will trigger re-render the component (react default behaviour).

so to avoid the error you can get values like that

```
let userTodos = todos ? todos.todos : []
```

OR by destructuring

```
let { todos: userTodos = []} = todos;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The bit `userTodos.map` is giving an error because `userTodos` is `todos.todos`, which is `undefined` on first render.

React is rendering everything, **then** running the `useEffect` that loads your data, then re-rendering with the new state.

Therefore you need to handle the initial state, where `todos` is `[]`, and thus you can't `map` on `todos.todos` as it doesn't exist.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. You can check if `todos.todos === undefined` at the top of your render method, and optionally render `"loading..."` if it is empty.
2. You can change your state so that you don't have `todo.todos` but the list of todos is directly on the root state list, that way you can `map` but it will be over an empty list, preventing the error. Do this by doing `setTodos(response.todos)` in the useEffect.

I would recommend doing both of the above, as then the user can see that things are loading if they have a slow connection, and also your state will be properly formatted so that future bugs like this are less likely.

Answer (score 0):

I understand number 2 issue:

```
const getToData = () => {
 
   console.log('todo', todos.todos)

   let userTodos = todos ? todos.todos : [];
   //here is where i get error
   return userTodos.map((current, index) => {
      return <Todo todo={current} key={index} />
   })
}
```

Hope it will help.